# Unknown permission com.android.vending.BILLING

Tags: android, android-permissions

I'm trying to set-up the In-App billing feature in my application. So far I followed this guide:

http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html

However when I'm specifying the Billing permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
```

the following message is appearing in LogCat:

```
Unknown permission com.android.vending.BILLING in package org.noi.activity
```

every time I start my application.

As I mentioned above I registered the Billing permission in my AndroidManifest.xml just as like in the [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#SetPermission):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="org.noivr.activity"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" android:minSdkVersion="9"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.vending.BILLING" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
...
</manifest>
```

I also [copied the In-app billing libraries](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#AddLibrary) into my project which now has the following structure:

- com.android.vending.billing
- com.android.vending.billing.util
- org.noi.activity
- org.noi.impl
- org.noi.const

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you testing on emulator?

A recent version of Google Play must be installed.

**Edit:**

No, it's not possible.

> You cannot use the Android emulator to test In-app Billing. The device
>   you use for testing must run a standard version of the Android 1.6 or
>   later platform (API level 4 or higher), and have the most current
>   version of the Google Play application installed.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing.html)

Google Play app is only licensed to device manufacturers.
In fact, you could find pirated version of Google Play app on the Internet, but it's not really recommended.

Comment: Yes, I'm testing on the emulator. Is it possible to install Google Play on that?

Comment: Added details in previous post.