# What is com.android.vending.BILLING, how to use it?

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-billing

I found some application use permission com.android.vending.BILLING,

```
uses-permission:'com.android.vending.BILLING'
```

I cannot find any infomation in source code and Google.

What is it? How to use it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15053868/unknown-permission-com-android-vending-billing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***This is for [In-App billing](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html).***

> In-app Billing on Google Play provides a straightforward, simple
>   interface for sending In-app Billing requests and managing In-app
>   Billing transactions using Google Play. The information below covers
>   the basics of how to make calls from your application to the In-app
>   Billing service using the Version 3 API.

Ref : [Documentation and how to use](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html)  and [Administering In-app Billing](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html)

Comment: More infos : http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html

Comment: Who provides this permission? How to make this permission available?

Comment: This is Google API so this provides this permission. And you have to write this permission into manifest to make available into your application..

Answer (score 3):

```
What is uses-permission:'com.android.vending.BILLING' ?
```

It is the permission required for integration of `Billing` in your android application.

```
How to use it?
```

**Reference:**
Have a look at [docs](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_integrate.html) for reference

```
I cannot find any infomation in source code and Google
```

**Sample app:**
Sample application is already provided in your `android-sdk`.kingly look at [Get Sample Application](http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample)

I hope it will be helpful !!

Comment: Who provides this permission? How to make this permission available?

Comment: You need to write it by yourself inside your `AndroidManifest.xml` file of your application.